# WPF do inputbindings take priotiy over keyboard focus?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My question probably sounds really strange, but basically I wanted to have a command (ZoomCommand) available at the application level. However, when I set it in the input bindings of the control like this:

```
 <UserControl>    
    <UserControl.InputBindings>
       <KeyBinding
              Command="{x:Static ViewModels:GraphViewerViewModel.ZoomToFitCommand}"
              Key="F"
              />
     </UserControl.InputBindings>

    <Searchbox />

    <OtherControl />
    <OtherControl />
    <OtherControl />
 </UserControl>
```

my search box stops working correctly. When I am typing in the searchbox, the command takes place when the hotkey is pressed. I want to have the command not take place when the searchbox has keyboard focus. I am actually rather surprised that bindings on keys at the control level take place even when a subcontrol has keyboard focus. Is there any way around this?

I just want the inputbinding to take place when most portions of the control have focus, but not have it take place when the searchbox has keyboard focus?

or do I have to just place my inputbinding manually on every control other than the searchbox, like I have done:

```
  <UserControl>    

    <Searchbox />

    <OtherControl>
       <OtherControl.InputBindings>
         <KeyBinding
              Command="{x:Static ViewModels:GraphViewerViewModel.ZoomToFitCommand}"
              Key="F"
              />
       </OtherControl.InputBindings>
    </OtherControl>


    <OtherControl>
       <OtherControl.InputBindings>
         <KeyBinding
              Command="{x:Static ViewModels:GraphViewerViewModel.ZoomToFitCommand}"
              Key="F"
              />
       </OtherControl.InputBindings>
    </OtherControl>

    <OtherControl>
       <OtherControl.InputBindings>
         <KeyBinding
              Command="{x:Static ViewModels:GraphViewerViewModel.ZoomToFitCommand}"
              Key="F"
              />
       </OtherControl.InputBindings>
    </OtherControl>
 </UserControl>
```

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do that. Could you post some of your code, the relevant XAML, code-behind, and any ViewModel code pertinent to your question?

Comment: were you able to get a solution for this?